# Function Dependancy PHP

Tags: php, mysql, class

So in php im trying to get a public variable in the database class that connects to a database when the class is created. Like so -

```
<?php

class database {    

    public $_link;


    public function __construct (){
       $this->_link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=swinkidc_student", "swinkidc_student", "");
    }


}
```

and...

```
<?php

class user{

    private $db;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new database;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ID of a user.
     * @param string $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserID($user){
        $query =  $_link->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :user");
        $query->bindParam(":user", $user);
        $query->execute();       
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result['user_id']; 
    }

    /**
     * Checks if given user is active.
     * @param string $user
     * @return bool Returns true/false if user is active.
     */
    public function isUserActive($user){

    }

}
```

If I extened database in user I can obviously refer to _link if i make it private and it will work, however, I don't think that i should inherit just for getting something like that..

Whenever i try the about i get : 
    Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/swinkidc/public_html/studentreach/core/authentication/user.php on line 18

As said, if i try the inheritance way it will work, I just don't feel like thats a great way of doing something like this.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks!

Comment: $this->db->_link->prepare() . You should call your db functions through the instance of your database class

Comment: you need to use $this->db->_link to get at the pdo object instead of $link.

Comment: Tried that, however I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined method database::prepare() in /home/swinkidc/public_html/studentreach/core/authentication/user.php on line 18"

Comment: There is no reason to wrap PDO

Comment: @sectus There are use cases like some additional methods you need everywhere. So that you can for example write `$class->select(["field"], "table", "id = $a");`. Which is shorter. (Even if I don't like it...)

Comment: likely the issue is that the database connection is not being established, in the __construct for your database you should check $this->_link to see if the db connection is valid

Comment: Anther note is that ever time you instantiate a new user object you are going to be creating a new db connection, a better approach would be to pass in a database object to the constructor of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link` is actually a property of  `database` and not a property of `user`. Therefore use:

```
$query =  $this->db->_link->...
```

Comment: Thank you good sir! Still trying to pickup OOP in PHP since im used to Procedural. Thank you! Will tick in 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the `$this->db->` before:

```
$query =  $this->db->_link->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :user");
```

Now, it should work; you're trying to access it directly. First access the Database-link holding object through the `$this->db` and only then access the property `$_link`.

If you need `$_link` as a variable because it's shorter, assign the object `$this->db->_link` to `$_link`:

```
$_link = $this->db->_link;
```

At the beginning of your getUserID function, then it'll work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try, in the User class, something as:

```
<?php

class user{

    private $db;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new database;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ID of a user.
     * @param string $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserID($user){
        $query =  $this->db->_link->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :user");
        $query->bindParam(":user", $user);
        $query->execute();       
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result['user_id']; 
    }

    /**
     * Checks if given user is active.
     * @param string $user
     * @return bool Returns true/false if user is active.
     */
    public function isUserActive($user){

    }

}
```

This can works as _link **is not** a **attribute** of User, but of **database**, and, if you extend the class database, it's acessible from the methods in link (at least in Java, i not know if the same way works for PHP), but not if you just instantiate it. It's just basic OOP.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Better to invert dependencies and wrap $db.

```
class database {

    private $_link;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) {
        $this->_link = $pdo;
    }

    public function getLink() {
        return $this->_link;
    }

    //other useful stuff

}

class user {

    private $_db;

    public function __construct(\database $db) {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    public function getDB() {
        return $this->_db;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ID of a user.
     * @param string $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserID($user) {
        $query = $this->getDB()->getLink()->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :user");
        $query->bindParam(":user", $user);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result['user_id'];
    }

    /**
     * Checks if given user is active.
     * @param string $user
     * @return bool Returns true/false if user is active.
     */
    public function isUserActive($user) {

    }

}
```

Usage

```
$user = new \user(new \database(new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=swinkidc_student", "swinkidc_student", "")));
```

Now you can configure your db connection outside of the class.